# Broken terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, library

I've got this message in `Terminal.app` at startup

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/gdbm/lib/libgdbm.4.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/zsh
  Reason: image not found

[Process completed]
```

I have found some links regarding this issue.

But the problem is that I can't run terminal app, so it's not possible for me to try `brew doctor` or other options.

It's not possible to reinstall `Terminal app`, other terminal app (iTerm2) is not running at all.

Is there a way to fix this problem without reinstalling OSX?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

1. Choose Shell → New Command….

   [image]
2. Run `chsh -s /bin/bash` and make sure to **de**select ‘Run command inside a shell’.

   [image]
3. Enter your user account password at the prompt to change your shell back to /bin/bash.

   [image]

Comment: A similar solution can be done from `iTerm2`. Add a new "Profile", make sure the "Command" is set from "Login shell" to "Command" and enter "/bin/sh" as the command (or /bin/bash, anything but zsh). That let's you get back into the command line, and you can then follow @Robert J Berger's solution below.

Comment: I was able to do this and then the steps from the "brew" answer followed by changing my shell back to `zsh`.

Answer (score 36):

Are you running zsh? I'm seeing a similar problem while running iTerm2. It seems to be a problem with zsh and not with Terminal or iTerm2. Just started happening to me.

If you had installed zsh with Homebrew and you are having that problem, what worked for me was:

`brew reinstall zsh && brew unlink zsh && brew link zsh`

If you didn't install zsh with Homebrew, then ignore this :-)

Answer (score 4):

Easier I think:
Download iTerm2 and
`brew update && brew upgrade zsh` worked for me ;-)

Comment: It's easy when you can not start a terminal :)

Comment: @megas Indeed, I used iTerm2 (forgot to mention that!) :)

Comment: OP already said in the question that "other terminal app (iTerm2) is not running at all"

Comment: In that case maybe trying https://github.com/zeit/hyper terminal could help

Answer (score 4):

To be able to fix my terminal/iterm2/hyper (all were broke because of broken zsh) I had to first change my terminal settings 'Shells open with' from a custom command to the default login shell

[image]

The trick from @grg didn't work for me. With these changes, I was able to update my zsh via homebrew as suggested in the other answers and all three apps worked as expected again.

Answer (score 2):

After searching for a while, this solved it for me:

```
brew reinstall ncurses
```

Comment: It's easy when you can start a terminal :)

Comment: In terminal you can a command with Shift+Command+N hotkey.